# Как сделать вложенный массив js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

У меня есть задача, вывести данные из одного `select > option` в другой `select > option`. То есть есть карточки товаров на пример с выбором цвета. В `option` задаются два значения `value` на английском и `text` на русском. Как сделать вложенный массив чтобы можно было передавать два значения в одном массиве? Ну и выводить так же в `option` два значения.
Сразу прошу прощения за некрасивое название переменных и возможно плохой код =)

[Код на Codepen](https://codepen.io/AndrewSD/pen/VwjXrwz)

```js
$('.c-item').each(function() {
  var inp_color_text = $(document).find(".card_item_color").text();
  // Объявляем переменные для цвета
  var inp_color = $(document).find('.card_item_color'),
      // var inp_color = $(document).find('.card_item_color'),
      t_c_inp = $(this).find('.card_item_color'),
      mas_color = [],
      t_c_mas = [],
      uniq_color = [],
  
      inp_color_v = [];

  // Объявляем переменные для типа
  var inp_type = $(document).find('.card_item_type'),
      t_t_inp = $(this).find('.card_item_type'),
      mas_type = [],
      t_t_mas = [],
      uniq_type = [],
      
      inp_type_v = [];

  function save() {
    // Все цвета
    for (var i = 0; i < inp_color.length; i++) {
      mas_color[i] = inp_color[i].value;
    }
    
    // Локальный цвет
    for (var i = 0; i < t_c_inp.length; i++) {
      t_c_mas[i] = t_c_inp[i].value;
    }

    // Локальный тип
    for (var i = 0; i < inp_type.length; i++) {
      mas_type[i] = inp_type[i].value;
    }

    // Локальный тип
    for (var i = 0; i < t_t_inp.length; i++) {
      t_t_mas[i] = t_t_inp[i].value;
    }
    
    uniq_type = mas_type.filter(function(item, pos) {
        return mas_type.indexOf(item) == pos;
    })
    
    uniq_color = mas_color.filter(function(item, pos) {
        return mas_color.indexOf(item) == pos;
    })

    // Выведем в консоль
    console.log(t_c_mas, t_t_mas, uniq_type, uniq_color);
  }
  save();

  let str_color = ' ';
  let str_type = ' ';
  for (var i = 0; i < uniq_color.length; i++ ) {
    if (uniq_color[i] !== undefined) str_color += '<option value="' + uniq_color[i] +'">' + uniq_color[i] + '</option>';
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < uniq_type.length; i++) {
    if (uniq_type[i] !== undefined) str_type += '<option value="' + uniq_type[i] +'">' + uniq_type[i] + '</option>';
  }
  $('.filter-items_color').html( '<option value="Выберите цвет">Выберите цвет</option>' + str_color);
  $('.filter-items_type').html( '<option value="Выберите тип">Выберите тип</option>' + str_type);
  
  $(this).closest('.c-item').attr('data-type', t_t_mas)
  
  $(this).closest('.c-item').addClass(t_c_mas);
  $(this).find('.set-color').html(t_c_mas + '');

  $(this).closest('.c-item').addClass(t_t_mas);
  $(this).find('.set-type').html(t_t_mas + '');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="filter filter-items_type">
</select>

<select class="filter filter-items_color">
</select>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="c-item" data-type="">
        <div class="card-product-body">
          <div class="card-product-item">
            <form>
              <select class="types">
                <option class="card_item_type" value="eco">Эконом</option>
                <option class="card_item_type" value="standart">Стандарт</option>
                <option class="card_item_type" value="premium">Премиум</option>
              </select>
              <select class="colors">
                <option class="card_item_color" value="white">Белый</option>
                <option class="card_item_color" value="black">Черный</option>
                <option class="card_item_color" value="yellow">Желтый</option>
              </select>
            </form>
            <div class="set-type"></div>
            <div class="set-color"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="c-item" data-type="">
        <div class="card-product-body">
          <div class="card-product-item">
            <form>
              <select class="types">
                <option class="card_item_type" value="eco">Сублимация</option>
                <option class="card_item_type" value="standart">Деколи</option>
              </select>
              <select class="colors">
                <option class="card_item_color" value="red">Красный</option>
                <option class="card_item_color" value="violet">Фиолетовый</option>
                <option class="card_item_color" value="gray">Серый</option>
              </select>
            </form>
            <div class="set-type"></div>
            <div class="set-color"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Закиньте всё, что вам нужно в json-объект и передавайте уже его.

Comment: @Quazimorda а можно небольшой пример?

Comment: @Quazimorda я понимаю что по типу такого нужно сделать, но я не понимаю как преобразовать в общий массив и вывести
`var inp_color = {
ru: $(document).find('.card_item_color').text,
en: $(document).find('.card_item_color')
}`

Comment: Я надеюсь, что не сама строка `$(document).find('.card_item_color').text` должна у вас подставляться, а текст из соответствующего объекта?

Comment: А вообще, [почитайте](https://learn.javascript.ru/json) на досуге.

Comment: @Quazimorda да, должен быть текст из $(document).find('.card_item_color').text и value из $(document).find('.card_item_color')

Comment: Так почитайте статью, ссылку на которую я привёл выше.

Comment: @Quazimorda проблему решил, спасибо. Решение прикреплю. Только у меня проблема в том что значения выводятся два раза. Возможно из за того что вывод идет через `each` ? Или может быть еще что то

Comment: `$('.c-item').each` сколько у вас блоков с классом c-item - столько раз оно и отработает. Если в этой функции повесили обработчик.